# How to print the List Of Tuples in multiple rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list 9 tuples. I need to print 3 tuples in each row. However I am able to print only 2 rows. May I know where I went wrong?

Below is the code as used in **Jupyter**.

```
List_Tuples = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)] 

Tuples_List = []    # To store 3 tuples at a time and print it
j=0
i=0

while i<9:          # Total 9 tuples from index 0 to 8
    if j<3:         # To restrict 3 tuples in a row 
        Tuples_List.append(List_Tuples[i])
        j+=1
        i+=1
        continue


    print(Tuples_List)
    j=0               # Reset j=0 for next row
    Tuples_List = []  # Emptying List for storing next 3 tuples
```

The output is:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]

[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Why did it not print `[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]`?

It will print `[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]` only if I change the condition to

```
while i <= 9:
```

**with list index out of range**

Comment: fix your indentations first in above code

Comment: It is properly indented in Jupyter.

Comment: No it is not in any editor. To start with there are no indentations after `if` statement. It's hard to understand later part of your code is part of `while` loop or not

Comment: Now, the code is Properly Indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I believe you mean to indent your code:

```
List_Tuples = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)] 

Tuples_List = []
j=0
i=0

while i<9:
    if j<3:
        Tuples_List.append(List_Tuples[i])
        j+=1
        i+=1
        continue
    print(Tuples_List)
    j=0
```

The reason it isn’t printing the last piece set of tuples is due to the continue statement. When a loop reaches a continue statement, it skips all following code in the loop and goes back to the start of the loop. Therefore the last print never happens. We can test this by printing `TuplesList` after the loop is finished.

```
print(TuplesList)
#[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)]
```

Comment: What is the solution if I need to print all the tuples?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only prints the generated `Tuples_List` when `i` is a multiply of 3. This, however, won't print the last list because the loop doesn't continue when `i` reaches 9, when it should.

Instead of `continue`, I recommend wrapping the `print` part in another condition that checks if `j == 3`:

```
while i<9:          -> Total 9 tuples from index 0 to 8
    if j<3:         -> To restrict 3 tuples in a row 
        Tuples_List.append(List_Tuples[i])
        j+=1
        i+=1
    if j == 3:
        print(Tuples_List)
        j=0               -> Reset j=0 for next row
        Tuples_List = []  -> Emptying List for storing next 3 tuples
```

See results online: http://tpcg.io/b1vqhG

Comment: @GtR In my answer, I **added** the extra condition. Please test the code before saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-698a96dee016> in <module>()
      5 
      6     if j<3:         # To restrict 3 tuples in a row
----> 7         Tuples_List.append(List_Tuples[i])
      8         j+=1
      9         i+=1

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: @GtR Did you test my code? It may be different that what you imagined.

Comment: I just tested. Your code gave the output with index error. I have already mentioned in the question that I get the output if i change the condition to **while(i<=9)**  instead of **while(i<9)** with index error.

Comment: @GtR My code **retains** `i < 9`, but replaced `continue` with `if j == 3`, as well as indentation adjustments. Please read it character-by-character, or just click the link I just added at the end of my answer.

Comment: @GtR I don't think so. Can you post the full code that still gives `IndexError`? A [mcve] is important for debugging questions.